# xcode with IBAction

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I’m trying to make an app in xcode. I have made a class called `myApp.m` and `.h`

In my `.m` I have these lines of code

```
- (void)loadApp

AlarmItem *item1 = [[[AlarmItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST2"] autorelease];
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:item1, nil];
RootViewController *rootController = (RootViewController *) [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
rootController.items = items;
```

and in my RootViewController I have an this method:

```
- (IBAction)RefreshMyApp:(id)sender {

    MyApp *myApp2 = [[[MyAppalloc] init] autorelease];
    [myApp2 loadData];
}
```

What I’m trying to do is calling the method from the myApp class and displayed in the tableView, but I always get an empty cell.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this meant to get you your UIApplication singleton? (i'm guessing MyAppalloc is a typo and should be MyApp alloc)

```
MyApp *myApp2 = [[[MyApp alloc] init] autorelease];
```

if so then you should be doing it like this:

```
MyApp *myApp2 = (MyApp*)[UIApplication sharedApplication];
```

If this is not the case you need to make it clearer what MyApp is (your app delegate?)

Comment: myApp is just void method, i could have called it load.

Comment: what i need is to reload the data from the method so it can be displayed in my cells.

Comment: Your writing this: MyApp *myApp2 = [[[MyApp alloc] init] autorelease];
what class is MyApp subclassing?

Comment: sorry MyApp is loadApp and not myApp

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your application running in singleton instance, if this is something kind of NSView or a particular control you want to refresh, you could call its particular refresh method like,
[NSTableView reload];
[NSTextField setString];
etc...

Comment: true, NS should be replaced with UI